# How to fix leaky sink in Virtual Families 2?

Tags: virtual-families-2

Out of nowhere my sink started leaking. I tried dragging my kid, mom, and dad toward the sink but nobody tried to fix it. Is there a plumber or something like that, or will it eventually go away? I tried turning the sink off but it didn't work. Is it a problem in the game or just an overall nuisance?

How do I fix the leaky sink?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to drag the person to the sink so they notice it is leaking. Then drop them in the workshop and they should get the tools they need to fix the sink.

Answer (score -2):

He is right. All you have to do is drag a person so they notice. Then drag them to the workshop and they will find the right tools.

Comment: This does nothing but regurgitate [Ashley Nunn's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/183194/30879) and thus add nothing new which hasn't already been said

Comment: If you agree with Ashley's answer, just upvote it.